# Export history from chome browser

Tags: macos, google-chrome, history

I'd like to be able to export the history from chrome so I can keep track of things like, for example, how many wikipedia articles I've looked at in the last week - all I'm really looking for is a url and a timestamp (I'm on a mac, if it turns out you can do this from the command line)

Where would I start? Would be great if it was the sort of thing that I could run as a cronjob...

Comment: I believe Chrome stores its history in an SQLite3 database. You could look for tools which can view such a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Chrome browser history be exported to an HTML file?](https://superuser.com/questions/602252/can-chrome-browser-history-be-exported-to-an-html-file)

Answer (score 10):

Close Chrome, then enter the following in your command line (the exact paths will vary, the following are for Mac OS X):

```bsh
/usr/bin/sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History > history.log <<EOF
select * from urls;
EOF
```

The history will then be in a file called history.log in your home directory (or any directory you switched to in Terminal)

Or for a user-friendly alternative, I recommend the [History Trends Unlimited](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends-unlimited/pnmchffiealhkdloeffcdnbgdnedheme) extension mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Or copy the History db file to elsewhere in the filesystem and do the sqlite analysis w/o having to quit Chrome.

Comment: deleting the forward slash after 'Application' in the code provided at least a working filepath in the finder, i guess the / is a typo?

Comment: @SibeJan, nope, in Terminal you have to put \s before space in filenames :)

Answer (score 4):

Also take a look at the [History Trends Unlimited](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends-unlimited/pnmchffiealhkdloeffcdnbgdnedheme) extension (full disclosure: I'm the developer). It does some of the analysis for you, but also has the option to export your history so you can do your own.

Comment: interesting, but when downloading the history, i'll get an alphabetical list of sites... or is something likte this "U1483029737222.5261" a time-stamp?

Comment: Yes, that is a timestamp (the numbers after the "U" are milliseconds since the Unix epoch). At the bottom of the Trends page is an "Export Raw Data" button; that will generate a file with a human-readable timestamp.

Comment: Great, @randy! You fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just created a Chrome extension that exports your Chrome history in csv and json called [Export History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-history/hcohnnbbiggngobheobhdipbgmcbelhh), and it works on mac (and linux and windows).

Comment: Awesome, Any Github Url?

Comment: Yup! https://github.com/christiangenco/chrome-export-history

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and came half-way: in the Finder, type shift-command-g (go to folder...) and fill in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History`. Now you've found the history sglite. Copy this file elsewhere or quit Chrome and open this file in e.g. [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)
But how to interpret the data, and find/make a simple list of URL's + timestamps... no idea!

update: found it. see comments above.

Comment: please improve your answer by including the information in the comments.