# Which folder Chrome stores my history on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, history

I've read some articles here that suggest that we are able to retrieve Chrome's history as SQLite databases:

- [Export history from chome browser](https://superuser.com/questions/359996/export-history-from-chome-browser)
- [How can I view "archived" Google Chrome history — i.e. history older than three months?](https://superuser.com/questions/414346/how-can-i-view-archived-google-chrome-history-i-e-history-older-than-three)

I can't seem to find the folder where these are supposed to be located. In the first article, the provided path was ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History, but there is no such directory in my filesystem. I am using Chrome 26.0.1410.65 on Mac OS X Lion. And I am signed in with my Google account.

Article http://unlockforus.blogspot.it/2008/09/how-opening-google-chrome-files-history.html provided in the last of the above is very useful, but it is only for Windows. Is there something similar to that but for Mac? Is there a way to find the folder where Chrome stores my history?

Answer (score 5):

Mine turned up here:

```
/Volumes/[Name_of_My_Home_Partition]/home/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/
```

I found it by opening the terminal and running the following command:

```
sudo find / -type d -iname "chrome"
```