# How to transfer Google Chrome history to IE?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, history

I switched to Google Chrome for about two months to try it out (on Windows 8.1) and now I am switching back to IE.

I can't be opening up Chrome every time I need to access my history. I also get suggestions in the url based on sites I visited previously. Is there any way to transfer my history?

Answer (score 1):

In order to import your history to Internet Explorer you must first export it from Google Chrome. You can find the official export instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816) yet I will summarize them in this answer.

```
First go to the Chrome menu. This is the three bars in the upper right hand corner. 

Second hover over "Bookmarks" and select bookmark manager.

Third click on organize.

Fourth select "Export bookmarks" and save it to an appropriate location.
```

You have now successfully exported your bookmarks. Now you must import them to Internet Explorer.

To do this:

```
First click on the favorites star.

Next hit the down arrow at the top.

Click import bookmarks. 

And follow the instructions from there.
```

In order to export your history there is another article that tell you how to do that [here](http://www.webtlk.com/2010/12/28/how-to-export-google-chrome-history/).

The basic summary however is:

```
Open Google Chrome.
Click the wrench icon located on the right side of the browser window.
Click History CTRL+H from the menu.
At this point you should be able to see a list ordered by date and containing your Internet history.
If you want to save and export everything, simply left click the first element on the list and highlight everything by pulling the mouse down.
Right click and select Copy.
Now, open a Word document and paste the content on it.
As you see, the whole Chrome history will be completely copied on the .doc file. Such a list will be ordered by date and time!
```

If you don't like that method they provide a more complex one [here](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

Comment: This works for history?

Comment: You're only mentioning bookmarks, and this doesn't work for history.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan Now I am.

Comment: Now how can I import this into IE?

Comment: @PhoenixLogan I'm not at a machine with IE. I'll check later but I would assume it'd be a copy pasta situation.

Answer (score 0):

Drawbacks of this method

You need to create batch file hence you need to work

Very long method (I searched but can't find any shortcut method )

Haven't tried so no guarantee

A crude idea

- Use [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html) software or any extension  capable of exporting chrome history. Other alternative [here](https://superuser.com/questions/602252/can-chrome-browser-history-be-exported-to-an-html-file)
- create a batch script to open and close each link ( links are present in the file you just saved in the above step) with internet explorer  [batch file to open multiple links in internet explorer](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ie-how-to-open-multiple-web-links-with-a-single-shortcut.994343/)

  [how to use for loop in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252979/windows-batch-call-more-than-one-command-in-a-for-loop)

  Hope it helps!!