# How can I export all downloads' links from chrome://downloads?

Tags: google-chrome

Some of the downloads fail sometime and I want to take all the links from Chrome Download list to a download manager.

If I save the chrome://downloads page I get an empty html file.

Is there a way that I can export all the downloads' links from Google Chrome Downloads page (you can access it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched the web and Chrome Web Store unfortunately there are no extensions to do that.

Only when I tried to make a script I discovered that the things are not that straightforward because there are a lot of nested shadow DOM elements, nevertheless I managed to write it.

Below is the code you need to paste in console(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) to get all the links.

```
ditems = document.querySelector("downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("iron-list").querySelectorAll("downloads-item");

var div = document.createElement('div');

[].forEach.call(ditems, function (el) {
var br = document.createElement('br');
var hr = document.createElement('hr');
div.appendChild(el.shadowRoot.querySelector("#url"));
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(hr);

});
document.body.innerHTML=""
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.head.style.innerHTML="";
```

After this you can save the resulting page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work anymore (Version 109.0.5414.120)
`This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the downloads links from Chrome's history database.

1. Locate the `History` file:

   - on macOS: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/`
   - on Windows: `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
   - on Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`
2. Make a copy of the file `History` to another location (you can't use the original while Chrome is open).
3. Now, you can extract the download links from the copied file, either using [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/) CLI, or using a GUI SQLite viewer such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). The download links are in the table `downloads_url_chains`.

Similar question that contains some useful sqlite3 commands: [Can Chrome browser history be exported to an HTML file?](https://superuser.com/questions/602252/can-chrome-browser-history-be-exported-to-an-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to get the URLs as of June 2023 (Version 112.0.5615.121):

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('downloads-manager')[0].$.downloadsList._physicalItems;
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i].$.name.innerHTML + ' - ' + items[i].$.url.innerHTML);
}
```

This script gets the download URLs along with file names in batches of 18. You may have to scroll the downloads page to load the next batch and run the script multiple times if you have more than 18 links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the NirSoft dedicated application, BrowserDownloadView (which I just tested on 2023-12-01). It worked splendidly with Chrome (latest version, on Windows 10 Enterprise)

Link:  https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_downloads_view.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1225192)